# Inverse of inverse of function?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, inverse

What is the inverse of inverse of a function (I assume the original function is invertible)? Is this the original function? Is it always true?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is the original function. By definition the inverse of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is (unique if it exist) the function $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $g\circ f:X\rightarrow X$ and $f \circ g:Y \rightarrow Y$ are the identities on $X$ and $Y$. With that I mean that $g\circ f(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$ and $f\circ g(y)=y$ for all $y\in Y$. Note that if $g$ is the inverse of $f$, then $f$ is the inverse of $g$ by symmetry of this definition.

Comment: great.thanks...

Comment: @Abdulkadir: But I like this one instead, because it is easy to undrestand than using groups. +1

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, the set of all bijective functions $$f: X → X$$ form a **group** with respect to the composition operator, so your claim makes sense.

Comment: great.thanks. This makes life easier :)

Comment: You are indeed helpful! + 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way of thinking about it. Consider the graph of the function $f$. The inverse of $f$ is the reflection of $f$ across the line $y=x$. If you reflect the inverse, you are reflecting it back, and you get the original function, $f$.

Comment: That only makes sense for functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. But OP's question appears to be much more general; at least its phrasing is much more general.